# What would happen if the copy() function received a smaller character array after receiving a bigger character array?

Tags: c

```
/* copy: copy 'from' into 'to'; assume to is big enough */
void copy(char to[], char from[])
{
  int i;

  i = 0;
  while ((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0') {
    ++i;
  }

}
```

If it were to be 2 character arrays:
`char line[1000];`
`char longest[1000];`

What would happen if "Hello" was previously assigned to line and copied to longest, and after that a shorter string got assigned to line again then copied to longest. They would get merged?

I already tried testing it by my own, but they don't get merged, indeed, they get just substituted, but why this happens rather than getting merged since they have different lengths?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251313/discussion-on-question-by-mpriv8-what-would-happen-if-the-copy-function-receiv).